# How to test client web api on postman

Tags: web-services, postman

I'm working on BP monitor app and trying to test web APIs according to the documentation with the OAuth 2.0 type authorization. But I'm facing some problems to get validate GET or POST response.

Could you please help me  how I can get the response of GET and POST web APIs.

Comment: There's no way for us to help you if you don't provide the same data you are using to test on postman

Comment: [https://ohi-oauth.numerasocial.com/connect/authorize?client_id=aviato-api&response_type=code&scope=bloodpressure+activity+openid+offline_access&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.aviato.com%2Foauth]

Comment: You have given us the url. Also give the POST body, headers, tokens and anything else. Please make it easy for us to help you. And edit the question and add these details, rather than adding in comments

Answer (score 0):

1) In the postman app, you first enter your API endpoint into the `URL` field.

2) Just to the left of the `URL` input, there is a dropdown to select whether you'd like to send your request as `GET` or `POST`.

3) To the right of the `URL` input, you can define any extra parameters needed.
These parameters are where you can define specific details needed for your test-case.

Postman also allows you to easily generate OAuth tokens for testing [(support for OAuth 1.0a and OAuth2)](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization).

Comment: I do the same but first can you please tell me how to I can authorizes  connection with and implement  the "Authorization Code Grant" flow defined in RFC 6749 Section 4.1 to initiate the application connection process

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide what you have done so far, so that we can better assist?  None of us can help troubleshoot the Authorization Server without more information about what you've done so far, what specific problems you're having, and examples of the code you're working with.

Comment: This is example  URL of GET response and and I'v passed original values in this url. After hit this url on postman I receive a response of  web page in preview on postman

Comment: https://ohi-oauth.numerasocial.com/connect/authorize?client_id=aviato-api&response_type=code&scope=bloodpressure+activity+openid+offline_access&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.aviato.com%2Foauth

Comment: Have you setup the "Authorization" tab in postman to generate a token?
You'll need to input your `Auth Url`, `Access Token URL`, `Client ID`, and `Client Secret` for postman to help you with your OAuth2 implementation.
Please refer to the URL I shared earlier for more information on this. Your question asks about help with GET/POST calls in postman, but that appears to be working properly. I think what you're really looking for is help in setting up your OAuth2 implementation, which is out of scope for this question, given the information you've shared.